# How to check if array contains a value given from an inputdialog

Tags: java

I have a problem in an exercise. The exercise is about teams. The user has to enter name and age of athlete, name and home of a team and name of the sport. when the user presses the "create athlete" button, a Joptionpane.inputdialog comes out to ask in what team he wants to place the athlete.

My problem is how to check if the team exists in arraylist teams, and how to place the athlete in that team.

```
if(e.getSource() == createAthlete){

    String nameA = athleteName.getText();

    Athlete A = new Athlete(nameA,Integer.parseInt(athleteAge.getText()));
    String team= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("In what team do you want to place the athlete?);
}


public class  Championship {

    private String name;
    private int durationMonths;
    private static ArrayList<Championship> cship = new ArrayList<Championship>();
    private static ArrayList<Club> clubs = new ArrayList<Club>();

    public Championship(String name, int durationMonths){
        this.name = name;
        this.durationMonths = durationMonths;

    }

    public static void addChampioship(Championship c){
        cship.add(c);
    }

    public static void addClub(Club club){
        clubs.add(club);
    }
}
```

It is quite urgent ,so thank in advance for your replies

Comment: _It is quite urgent_ this wont improve the response time in the slightest

Comment: The [ArrayList docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) are a good place to start, particularly `ArrayList#contains(Object o)`.

Comment: My mistake,its the first time I post something here. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clubs.contains(club)` returns `true` if club is already there or `false` otherwise.

You just have to implement `equals()` for your data object (`Club`, `Championship` etc).

However if you need uniquness why not just to use set instead of list?

`private static Collection<Club> clubs = new HashSet<Club>();`

In this case even if you add the same club twice only one instance will present. 
But in this case you should additionally implement `hashCode()` for your data objects.

BTW please pay attention on type that I used. You wrote `ArrayList` (i.e. concrete class at the left half of assignment. I wrote interface `Collection` that let me ability to easily change cocrete implementation (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, `LinkedHashSet` *etc*) without affecting other code.

Comment: An important side note that she should be made aware of - `HashSet` does not maintain insertion order.  If she cares about order, she should use `private static Collection<Club> clubs = new LinkedHashSet<Club>();`.  +1

Comment: Actually I am not familiar with HashSet, so I'll try equals(). Than you very much for your quick response